# How to make specific routes in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to make routes with specific routes.
Right now, I'm able to go between the routes but I don't know how to make it specific.
For example:

```
 <Route path='/' element={<HomePage/>} />
 <Route path='/User' element={<UserPage/>} />
```

So right now I can go between the pages.

but if I write anything else in the URL, like: "localhost:3000/gibberish",
it will go there, and of course, nothing will show on the page.

instead, I want it to redirect the client to a page that I have created, "Page not found".

Any idea how I can do that?

Thank you so much in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Use `*` to redirect to your component when no other routes match

```
 <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
```

Answer (score 1):

[React Router documentation](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/no-match) provides an example to handle 404/NotFound.

You essentially need to specify a wildcard with `*` that will match everything that is not defined in your router already.